# Javascript Unable to Change Input Text Field Value

Tags: javascript, html

When testing out various functions for this decentralized application (dApp), I've run into an issue involving inputting a desired value in a text field. 
My objective is to input a desired input value into the text field to the left of the 'Deposit' button.

Website Link: 
https://fragtoken.io/box

```js
var inputvalue = 100;
var inputamount = document.getElementsByClassName("input-reset frag-deposit tc pa3 mr2 ")[1]; //second element with this class name
    inputamount.value = inputvalue;
```

```html
<input class="input-reset frag-deposit tc pa3 mr2 " type="text" style="margin-left:18px;" value="0" data-reactid=".0.0.2.0.5.1.0.1.9.0" />
<input class="input-reset frag-deposit tc pa3 mr2 " type="text" style="margin-left:18px;" value="0" data-reactid=".0.0.2.0.5.1.0.1.9.0" />
```

When this snippet is executed, the desired input value of '100' flashes in the text field and disappears in under a second.

I was able to get text input into this app's text field successfully with Python using the Selenium environment. I am relatively new to Javascript, but have been able to get this basic action of inputting a new value on other websites and other apps. I'm not sure if there is some different structure or detail that I am not aware of for this particular app, like maybe it has to do with the data-reactid or a different element in the html code.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I edit your question with your exact code to a snippet and it seems that your code works..

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with either the HTML or Javascript. It is unclear why you want to set the default value of the input to 100 using Javascript as this is a user input. Why don't you just set the value attribute to 100 `value="100"` in the HTML.

Otherwise there might be Javascript somewhere else in the source code which might be resetting the value of the input.

Comment: I'm using Chrome snippets to test out some automation functions. I want to deposit a desired amount every hour. I understand the setTimeout and the clicking functions that would be used but I cannot get the value input to remain in the text field.